# SharePoint root site master page

Tags: master-page

I have a root site and other site collections in same web application port

If I edit the root site master page, Will it affect other site collections in this port?

Regards,

Abraham

Answer (score 0):

Abraham, it depends if all of your site collection implement the same master page, then changing your master page will affect all of the other site collection. But if you have different master pages for each site collection then it will not.

Basically you can set master page on each site collection different, as a site collection you can see a container for webs, so applying master page to a site collection will affect all webs inside that site collection.

I hope my question was good, if you require more information, let me know.

Happy coding!